# ROS package for 4-DOF Arm

Tags: ros, arm-navigation, arm-kinematics, move-arm, arm-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking at making my own 4 DOF arm. I see that there was a package "move_arm" that handled motion planning and servo control for an arm, that was made for ROS Groovy.

Would there be any modern options that exist? If not, where should I get started when trying to make something that handles the IK and motion planner?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276287/ros-package-for-4-dof-arm/) by [hni19](https://answers.ros.org/users/30735/hni19/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2017-11-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-11-20**:
Starting point: http://moveit.ros.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[move_arm](http://wiki.ros.org/move_arm) was part of `arm_navigation`, which has long since been deprecated.

Its (spiritual) successor is [moveit](http://wiki.ros.org/moveit).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hni19](https://answers.ros.org/users/30735/hni19/) on 2017-11-20**:
This looks very promising and a great place to start! Thanks a ton! I'll definitely continue reading through it now.